# Discord.py | add role to someone

Tags: python, discord.py

I have trouble with making an "add role" command in discord.py. I don't know what is wrong; it just doesn't work.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def addrole(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Test")
    await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

Comment: Are you getting any output in the terminal you're running the bot from? Are you on the rewrite branch? (if you aren't sure the answer is probably no).  Are you using `discord.ext.commands.Bot`?

Comment: Yes im usinng     discord.ext.commands.bot and i have output in terminal with succesfull load but in async def addrole(HERE) i have problem

Answer (score 13):

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Admin") # This must be exactly the name of the appropriate role
async def addrole(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Test")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

I think the only real mistake in your code is the lack of `pass_context=True` in the `@bot.command` decorator.  You may have seen some code without this, but that likely belongs to the experimental "rewrite" branch of [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py)

Comment: `discord.Message.author` is type `Union[discord.Member,discord.abc.User]`, neither of which seem to have a `server` attribute.

Comment: A lot of the object names (and a bunch of other stuff) got changed when discord.py released version 1.0, which was a couple of years ago. You should double check old answers here against the official docs for the correct interfaces. I believe the modern way to do this is to use `ctx,guild`, but I haven't used this library for a few years.

Answer (score 12):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.name}, {user.name} has been giving a role called: {role.name}")
```

Answer (score 7):

```py
roleVer = 'BOT' #role to add
user = ctx.message.author #user
role = roleVer # change the name from roleVer to role

await ctx.send("""Attempting to Verify {}""".format(user))
try:
    await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=role)) #add the role
except Exception as e:
    await ctx.send('There was an error running this command ' + str(e)) #if error
else:
    await ctx.send("""Verified: {}""".format(user)) # no errors, say verified
```

Comment: nvm, forgot to remove `user`

Answer (score 4):

```py
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

usage: !addrole [member] [role]

NOTE : the bot can only give roles lower than him !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a role command for you!

```
@client.command('role')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) #permissions
async def role(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, role : discord.Role):
  if role.position > ctx.author.top_role.position: #if the role is above users top role it sends error
    return await ctx.send('**:x: | That role is above your top role!**') 
  if role in user.roles:
      await user.remove_roles(role) #removes the role if user already has
      await ctx.send(f"Removed {role} from {user.mention}")
  else:
      await user.add_roles(role) #adds role if not already has it
      await ctx.send(f"Added {role} to {user.mention}")
```

Aswell as errors:

```
@role.error
async def role_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send('**:x: | You do not have permission to use this command!**')
```

Now that its finished, you have a role command!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a current solution I was stuck on this for a while but you can use `ctx.message.author.add_roles(get(guild.roles, name="Test"))` to add a role to a user. (Assuming the role exists)

You can grab the guild information with `await bot.get_guild(id)` and you can basically call anything from `guild.roles` to `guild.bans` lol

DEMO

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

TOKEN = ""

intents=discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command(pass_context=True) # pass_context=True is important here.
async def go(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID) # Get guild information
    role = get(guild.roles, name="Test") # Get specific role from guild
    await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role) # Add role here.
    await ctx.send('Role added!') # Confirm roles added

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Make sure your bot has permission to add the role your looking for and that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
role = discord.utils.get(ROLE_ID)
member.add_roles(role)
```

Important: bot can't manage roles that above him