# How to give a variable a role in discord.py - Discord Python

Tags: python, variables, discord, discord.py

I want to specify that the variable "role" is a role that I created named 'testcom'. So that when i call it in user.add_roles, it will give the user the specified role. Any help? Thank you.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def testcom(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = ##help here ##
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("done")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076798/discord-py-add-role-to-someone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py | add role to someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076798/discord-py-add-role-to-someone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the role id from the guild:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def testcom(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role int here)
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles,name="name_of_the_role_you_need")
```

This way `role` is a variable that contains a `discord.Role` object.

---

You can also get the role by `int` id:

```
role = ctx.guild.get_role(0238023802302) # put your id
```

---

I would suggest you to read the content of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nonchris/cab381064d364488cce46a1da1e223ac) too.