# Why is this command not working? is it me or the code?

Tags: python, discord.py

When I try to use the command `!addrole` it is supposed to give me the role but the bot won't.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents = intents)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("ADMIN") 
async def addrole(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Test")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

The things I have tried are making it so the bot has the highest rank on the server, making sure the bot has administrator permissions, changing the command I used to `!addrole [member] [role]`, but none of that worked. I'm also not getting any errors and yes I do have the ADMIN role. Is it the code or is it me using the command wrong? If so what command should I use?

Comment: Is the role "ADMIN" all caps?

Comment: In the server I'm testing the bot in it is in all caps

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified, is the role "Admin" or "ADMIN" or "admin" or something else?

Comment: it is "ADMIN" in the server

Comment: Try and log errors? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164639/7678067

Comment: when I use that error code and use the command nothing happens

Comment: Can you add a log to "addrole" see if function is being run at all?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry I'm very new to this

Comment: Use, `print('something in here')`

Comment: it doesn't print anything. So would that mean I am using the wrong command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing message intents.

```py
intents.messages = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = intents)
# ...
```

Follow the instructions here to enable message intents like any other intent on the bot's developer portal:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: to enable all the intents, you can use `intents = discord.Intents.all()` which is recommended if you don't know what intents you should use. otherwise, use `intents = discord.Intents()` and use `intents.<intent name> = True` to enable that intent. The link attached in the answer contains more information on this, as well as what intent names there are.

Comment: It is still not working. Would you know of any reason why? Am I using the right command of "!addrole"?

Comment: are you sure your bot is actually running? please make sure your bot is online first before doing the command.

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is running when I use the command